# Show that there is no sequence with infinitely many zero's that converges to a non-zero number.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I've already finished what I think is a valid proof by contradiction, but I would like to know if it's correct.

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence with infinetly many $0$s, such that $\lim(a_n) = a \ , a\neq0$. Then $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-a| < \epsilon \ ,\forall n>N$.

Let's choose an epsilon such that $0<\epsilon<|a|$. Knowing that $(a_n)$ has infinitely many $0$s, then $\exists n>N$ such that $a_n=0$. That way, for that particular $n$, we have that $|0-a|=|a|<|a|$, which is absurd.We can now conclude that only one of the following happens: $(a_n)$ doesn't converge to a non-zero number or $(a_n)$ has a finite number of $0$s.
Is this proof correct?

Before getting to this result I was trying to achieve that $\forall n > N$ we necessarily have that $a_n > 0 \ \lor \ a_n < 0$, but I was unable to do it. Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: Don't write quantifiers either in symbols or in words on both sides of a predicate as the result is ambiguous: "there exists an $N$ such that $...$ for all $n$" could either mean $\forall n \exists N( \ldots)$ or $\exists N\forall n(\ldots)$ and these are not logically equivalent in general. (Most people would also ask you to use words rather than quantifier symbols.)

Comment: As an aside, its oftentimes easier to follow if you actually just *choose* an appropriate $\varepsilon$, say $\frac{|a|}{2}$ its quite obvious here that there is an appropriate $\varepsilon$ but it is important to note that formally, you need to prove that such an $\varepsilon$ exists, it could happen during a proof that you assume the existence of something that doesn't exist, and obtain a legitimate contradiction, but not one that contradicts your original assumption, and only the assumption of the existence of the object

Comment: More direct: If a sequence converges, every subsequence converges to the same limit. But here you can construct a subsequence that is constant zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence with infinetly many $0$s, such that $lim(a_n) = a \ , a\neq0$. Then $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-a| < \epsilon \ ,\forall n>N$.
>
> Let's choose an epsilon such that $0<\epsilon<|a|$. Knowing that $(a_n)$ has infinitely many $0$s, then $\exists n>N$ such that $a_n=0$. That way, for that particular $n$, we have that $|0-a|=|a|<|a|$, which is absurd.We can now conclude that only one of the following happens: $(a_n)$ doesn't converge to a non-zero number or $(a_n)$ has a finite number of $0$s.

- Note the spelling of "infinitely".
- Limits should be typeset with `\lim`.
- Whenever possible, you should allow the typesetting engine (MathJax, LaTeX, whatever) to do its job.  In several places, you have forced the typesetting engine to insert spaces in a manner that I, personally, find unaesthetic.  Also, note that there should be spaces after the punctuation at the end of a sentence.
- What is $N$?  The way the definition of convergence works, first $\varepsilon$ is chosen, and then a value of $N$ (which depends on $\varepsilon$) can be chosen.
- As a general rule (though this is a matter of taste), I prefer to use more words and less notation, unless the notation *really* helps to make the point, and I don't like to put two different notational phrases right next to each other (as I find that this makes things harder to read.
- Again, as a matter of opinion, good mathematical writing should be written in the imperative.  I don't like the first-person plural (i.e. the mathematical "we"), though people do use it.  (I find it affected.)

On a scale of "Needs Improvement" / "Satisfactory" / "Excellent", I would give this proof a "satisfactory".  The writing is a little sloppy,  and the ambiguity about the selection of $N$ is actually something of a real problem.

Taking the general idea and structure of your proof (which is basically correct), I would write something like the following:

> Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a0$ and $a_n = 0$ for infinitely many $n$.   Then for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N$ implies that $|a_n - a| < \varepsilon$.
>
> For contradiction, suppose that $a \ne 0$, and fix some $\varepsilon$ such that $0 < \varepsilon < |a|$ and choose some $N \in\mathbb{N}$ so large that $n > N$ implies that $|a_n - a| < \varepsilon$.  As the sequence contains infinitely many zeros, there exists some $n > N$ such that $a_n = 0$.  For that $n$
> $$ \varepsilon > |a_n - a| = |0 - a| = |a|. $$
> But $\varepsilon$ was chosen so that $|a|>\varepsilon$, which is a contradiction.  Therefore $a = 0$.

Comment: The imperative is probably right for homework exercises, but the first person plural is just the thing when properly used in papers and textbooks. N.b., it should not be read as the royal "we", but as the author and the reader talking together about the subject matter  they are exploring.

Comment: @RobArthan As I said, I think it is a matter of taste.  Personally, I *despise* the mathematical "we" in any context (textbooks, student homework, published papers, etc).  As I said above, I think that it sounds affected and pretentious.  It isn't to my taste.  That doesn't mean it is wrong, just that *I* don't like it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will keep these points in mind next time I write here. I'll also be more careful about the undefined N!